# C++ Template friend odd behavior

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'm seeing something I can't explain in the following code.  Under VS6, VS9, and GCC T2::foo2() gives the error: 'bar' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'C1'.  But if you remove C1::bar(), it compiles and runs correctly, even though T2 is still accessing the protected C1B:bar(), which you would think would be the same problem.

Note, that in T2::foo2() you could cast 'pT1' to be a 'T1*' and everything is fine, but that still does not explain why C1B::bar() is allowed, but C1::bar() is not.

```
template<class S> class T2;

template<class T> class T1
{
    //template<class T> friend class T2;  --> this doesn't compile under VS6
    friend class T2<T>;

    protected:
        virtual void bar() { printf("T1\n"); }
};

template<class S> class T2
{
    public:
        void foo1(T1<S> *pT1) { pT1->bar(); }  // --> ok, makes sense, this works either way
        void foo2(S *pT1) { pT1->bar(); }  // --> this fails to compile if C1::bar() is defined, but works for C1B::foo() ???
};

class C1 : public T1<C1>
{
    protected:
        virtual void bar() { printf("C1\n"); }  // --> comment this out and foo2 will compile
};

class C1B : public  C1
{
    protected:
        virtual void bar() { printf("C1B\n"); }
};

class C2 : public  T2<C1>
{
};

void test(void)
{
    C1B c1b;
    C2 c2;
    c2.foo1(&c1b);
    c2.foo2(&c1b);  // --> fails to compile if C1::bar() exists
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, the type of the parameter `S` in `foo2` is `C1`.  The friend relationship exists between `T2<S>` and `T1<S>`.  Although `C1` derives from `T1<C1>` it does not become a friend of all the friends of `T1<C1>`.

In the expression `pT1->bar`, `bar` is found in `C1` and, as the friendship is not passed down to the derived class, it is private.

Your example is using virtual functions so this can be addressed by explicitly referring to the `bar` that **is** a friend of our class:

```
void foo2(S *pT1) { pT1->template T1<S>::bar(); }
```

The access check now succeeds.

The reference for this in the '03 C++ standard is in 11.4/10, where it simply says:

> Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive.

Thanks to Potatoswatter for his comment.  By using the `qualified-id` for the `id-expession`, we disable virtual dispatch (5.2.2/1):

> If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in the class member access expression is a qualiﬁed-id, that function is called.

We can add a non-virtual dispatcher, or we can first convert the parameter to the base type and then make the call:

```
 void foo2(S *pT1) { static_cast< T1<S>* > (pT1)->bar(); }
```

Virtual dispatch now takes place as required.

Comment: +1 just for the zany function call syntax, but this defeats the `virtual` functionality which OP probably wants. Would be better to implement a non-virtual dispatcher function which is accessible by friends and serves to call a private virtual `bar`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  My initial reaction was that this was the case too - however, my test with g++ showed it did the virtual dispatch.  I'll try to dig this out of the standard.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: DOH!  The OP has two calls to the function, when I tested I saw the output from the first and assumed that my change worked.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for you replies.  It was actually a two part question, which I tried to point out, but maybe wasn't clear.  The first was that I was really interested in getting the foo2() version, which I think you answered.  But the second, actually more interesting question, is why does everything in the example code compile (as-is) if you comment out C1::bar()?  It would seem that if "Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive" then certainly T2::foo2() could not call C1B::bar()... but alas, it does, on all three compilers.

Comment: @Greg:  Right so with 'C1::bar' declared, the compiler finds *that* bar, checks if we have appropriate access to that name and, since we don't, it fails to compile.  The key is that access checking takes place on the name found **not** on the function eventually called by the virtual dispatch.  C1B::bar is only called after we've checked access to the name in the base class.